# input certain field from dropdown and then use another field from that row (csv file) in the search

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm new to Splunk and I am in the process of writing a Splunk query which takes in a key from the dropdown option on a dashboard and I want to then extract a different row (specifically domain) associated with that key in the csv file and then use it in the search to filter it by domain.

The query which I currently wrote is:

```
basequery 
| lookup tenant.csv key as tenant_key output domain as Domain
| search tenant_key = $selected_client$
| stats count
```

I just want to display a count filtered by domain associated with the key provided by the dropdown. I'm not quite sure what is wrong or how to go about it.

Comment: What output do you get from this query?

Is 'stat' just a typo when writing the question?  The correct command is `stats`.

You say you want to filter by domain, but domain is not used after it is fetched from the lookup table.

For better performance, put `search` before `lookup`.

Comment: ah sorry, yeah that is a typo. how do I use the domain fetched? I just want the count of the events hit from my baseQuery filtered by the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.  Putting `tenant_key` in the base query limits the search to events with the selected client.  Then the lookup maps tenant to domain. Finally, do the count.

```
basequery tenant_key=$selected_client$ 
| lookup tenant.csv key as tenant_key output domain as Domain 
| stats count
```

Comment: tenant_key is only valuable for looking up the domain from the csv file and then I want to display events occurred only in that domain.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. fyi, the tenant key does not provide any value in the search. I need the tenant key to extract the domain from the csv file and then use that domain in my search.

Comment: If tenant_key can be used in a lookup then it should be usable in the base search.  The value is provides is to limit the events searched to those with the specified tenant_key and (via the lookup) domain.  BTW, the `stats` command does not display events - just roll-up stats.  To see the actual events, omit `stats`.

Comment: sorry if this is basic question butwhere are we using the domain in your search? in regards to the tenant key, if I just do the search on the key, it won't return anything since the logs don't have the tenant key (they have the domain)

Comment: I assumed you were looking up the domain name because it wasn't available otherwise.  Here's an alternative query: `basequery [ | inputlookup tenant.csv key as tenant_key output domain | search tenant_key = $selected_key$ | fields domain | format ]

Comment: the logs have the domain information on there to search for it but it does not have the key. so I need to look up the key in the csv file to get the corresponding domain name and then use domain name in the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197957/discussion-between-richg-and-normal-one).